# icedtea-web 1.5 needs confirmation to run trusted applet

Tags: icedtea

I've got ubuntu 14.04 64 bit.
I'm using firefox 29 and icedtea as java.

"About:plugin" in firefox: IcedTea-Web Plugin (using IcedTea-Web 1.5 (1.5-1ubuntu1))

Now I've setup firefox to ask to activate before launching java from trusted sites.

Whenever I launch any service that uses java I get the "java web start" applet that asks if I'm sure if I want to run this application.

I can say yes or no, and tick a box to remember the answer.

**This is the problem at hand; icedtea-web can't remember the answer if I check the "yes" button.**

Java works fine when it is started.

I have tried to purge all java and reinstalled openjdk-7, java web start and icedtea web-controlpanel.

I've tried to play around with the control panel for java web start but with no success.

Comment: It really looks like that the problem is related to icedtea, rather than firefox, because the result is the same if I run in safe mode and constant allowing all plugins.

Comment: Can you provide the link to the java applet you are using?

Comment: Link to one of the applets:
http://www.java.com/en/download/installed.jsp

Comment: In the icedtea-web settings program, the button menu is "extended applet security", and according to this:
http://icedtea.classpath.org/wiki/Extended_Applets_Security
the icedtea-web are supposed to store settings here, if I understand this correctly that is.

In this section there are no setting stored - at all.

Comment: After some searching I've found a thread at:
http://ubuntudanmark.dk/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=18765

It is in Danish, so to boil it down the OP describes the same problem as i have, and others too.
It seems that if you are running chromium the icedtea-web works fine.

Comment: The conclusion is that since firefox 29 were launched the problem occurred, and that sounds right to me, since the problem first occurred after the firefox update.
But what eludes me is still, that it is a icedtea-web applet that doesn't write to the ".appletTrustSettings" file in the /home/.config/icedtea-web folder

Comment: Oops forget my comment about the plug-in working in Chromium. Sorry.